# php cookie tamper-proofing

Tags: php, security, cookies, hash

I use this code on my website:

```
<?php
$pass = "61e7680d2ac47e5b9e3c82118fae6e3cfcddff285ac75bb82872bb01f24ac657";
function valCookie(){
    if (isset($_COOKIE['session'])){
        $cookie = json_decode(hex2bin($_COOKIE['session']), true);
        global $pass;
        $hash = hash('sha256', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $cookie['uid'] . 
        $cookie['expiry'] . $pass);
        $uid = $cookie['uid'];
        if ((hash_unique($hash, $cookie['hash'])) && ($cookie['expiry'] > time())){
            return $uid; //return user id.
            }
        }
    }
function hashCookie($uid, $expiry){
    global $pass;
    $cookie['uid'] = $uid;
    $cookie['expiry'] = $expiry;
    $cookie['hash'] = hash('sha256', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $cookie['uid'] . 
    $cookie['expiry'] . $pass);
    $hexCookie = bin2hex(json_encode($cookie));
    setcookie("session", $hexCookie, $expiry);
    if(strlen($uid)){
        return true;
        }
    }
?>
```

Is it safe to use this to tamper-proof my cookies? I include the time in the hashing to expire the cookie. is this a secure way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to [roll your own crypto](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it).

> Is it safe to use this to tamper-proof my cookies? I include the time in the hashing to expire the cookie. is this a secure way of doing it?

No, you're using a SHA256 hash of values that can largely be provided by attackers instead of HMAC-SHA256. Without HMAC, SHA256 is vulnerable to [length-extension attacks](https://blog.skullsecurity.org/2012/everything-you-need-to-know-about-hash-length-extension-attacks).

Instead, consider (in order of preference):

1. [PASETO](https://paseto.io), which provides tamper-resistant tokens with a high security margin. The only downside is that they're not immune to replay attacks.
2. [JWT](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt), with HS256. The linked library will allow you to securely only ever allow HS256, thereby side-stepping 99.9% of [JWT security fails](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid).
3. [Halite's `Cookie` class](https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/master/doc/Classes/Halite.md). Halite is a usability wrapper for libsodium, a modern cryptography library that now ships with PHP 7.2.